# CakePHP 3 patch entity creates new associated entities

Tags: php, cakephp, associations, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to update a *ClientContactName* entity, using the `patchEntity()` function, which has a *ClientContactAddresses* association. The *ClientContactName* entity updates as I'd expect. However, even though the *ClientContactAddress* is an existing entity, the `patchEntity()` function creates a **new** *ClientContactAddress* entity, and adds it to the table when saving.

If I include a hidden `id` field in the view and add the `id` as an `accessibleField` in the associated array, it does indeed update the existing *ClientContactAddress*, but I'm struggling to imagine that this is the correct way of going about things.

My question is: how do I code the patching function so that existing associations are updated instead of new ones being created?

The relationship is *ClientContactName* `hasMany` *ClientContactAddresses*. And below is my code without the hidden `id` field and `accessibleField` adjustment.

My `edit()` function in the controller looks like this:

```php
public function edit($id = null) 
{
    $clientContactName = $this->ClientContactNames->get($id, [
        'contain' => [
            'Clients',
            'ClientContactAddresses'
        ]
    ]);
    if ($this->getRequest()->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getData();
        $clientContactName = $this->ClientContactNames->patchEntity(
            $clientContactName,
            $data, [
                'associated' => ['ClientContactAddresses']
            ]
        );
        if ($this->ClientContactNames->save($clientContactName)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The client contact has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'Clients', 'action' => 'view', $clientContactName->client->id]);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('The client contact could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }
    $this->set(compact('clientContactName'));
}
```

The view looks like this:

```html
<div class="container-fluid clearfix col-lg-10">
    <?= $this->Form->create($clientContactName) ?>
    <fieldset>
        <!--bits that matter-->
        <div class="row stack-row">
            <div class="col-6">
                <?= $this->Form->control('first_name') ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <?= $this->Form->control('last_name') ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?= $this->element('address_form', ['showTopper' => true, 'entity' => 'client_contact_addresses.0']) ?>
    </fieldset>
    <?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit'), ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
</div>
```

and this is the element:

```php
<?php
$prefix = ((empty($entity)) ? '' : $entity . '.');
if (!empty($showTopper)):
?>
<div class="row stack-row">
    <div class="col">
        <legend class="sub-topper"><?= __('Address') ?></legend>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<div class="row stack-row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <?php
        echo $this->Form->control($prefix . 'address_1');
        echo $this->Form->control($prefix . 'address_2');
        echo $this->Form->control($prefix . 'address_3');
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
<!--etc.-->
```

Prior to patching, the relevant parts of the entity are as I would expect, ie `[new]` is set to `false`:

```
object(App\Model\Entity\ClientContactName) {
    'id' => (int) 1,
    'first_name' => 'xxxx',
    'last_name' => 'xxxx',
    'client_id' => (int) 19,
    'client_contact_addresses' => [
        (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\ClientContactAddress) {
            'id' => (int) 12,
            'address_1' => 'xxxx',
            'address_2' => 'xxxx',
            'address_3' => 'xxxx',
            etc...
            'client_contact_name_id' => (int) 1,
            '[new]' => false,
            '[accessible]' => [
                'address_1' => true,
                'address_2' => true,
                'address_3' => true,
                etc.
                'client' => true
             ],
            '[dirty]' => [],
            '[original]' => [],
            '[virtual]' => [],
            '[hasErrors]' => false,
            '[errors]' => [],
            '[invalid]' => [],
            '[repository]' => 'ClientContactAddresses'
     }],
     //..//
```

The request data shows the address field values. Though because I don't have a hidden `id` field, no `id` value occurs:

```
'first_name' => 'xxxx',
'last_name' => 'xxxx',
'client_contact_addresses' => [
    (int) 0 => [
        'address_1' => 'xxxx',
        'address_2' => 'xxxx',
        'address_3' => 'xxxx',
        etc.
    ]
],
```

And after patching, the new entity is created, ie `[new]` is set to `true`:

```
object(App\Model\Entity\ClientContactName) {

    'id' => (int) 1,
    'first_name' => 'xxxx',
    'last_name' => 'xxxx',
    'client_id' => (int) 19,
    'client_contact_addresses' => [
        (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\ClientContactAddress) {
            'address_1' => 'xxxx',
            'address_2' => 'xxxx',
            'address_3' => 'xxxx',
            etc.
            '[new]' => true,
            '[accessible]' => [
            'address_1' => true,
            'address_2' => true,
            'address_3' => true,
            etc.
            'id' => true
            ],
            '[dirty]' => [
                'address_1' => true,
                'address_2' => true,
                'address_3' => true,
                etc.
            ],
            '[original]' => [],
            '[virtual]' => [],
            '[hasErrors]' => false,
            '[errors]' => [],
            '[invalid]' => [],
            '[repository]' => 'ClientContactAddresses'

        }],
     //..//
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to make the `id` field accessible, in fact you really shouldn't do that as it can be a possible security risk.

All you need to do is to pass the ID of the record in the data. The marshaller needs that value in order to be able to figure out what existing entity to patch with the rest of the data.

Using a hidden field to pass the ID is absolutely fine. The form helper will automatically choose a hidden field when generating a control for a primary key column.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Saving Data > Converting HasMany Data](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/saving-data.html#converting-hasmany-data)**
- **[Cookbook > Views > Helpers > Form > Creating Inputs for Associated Data](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/views/helpers/form.html#associated-form-inputs)**

Comment: Thanks. Man, you know CakePHP well. Are you the designer of it? If you are, I'd like to let you know that I think it's an amazing piece of work.

Comment: @Ambie You're welcome, and no, I'm neither the founder nor a core developer, just a user and occasional contributor.